# JTree with nodes generated at run-time

Tags: java, jtree

My program builds a tree based on input data. Before running the program, there is no way of knowing how many nodes should be created and where the position of the nodes (under which parent) should be.

Using `JTree`, we can add nodes easily *if* we, beforehand, are aware of the structure.

E.g.

```
//create the root node
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");
/create the child nodes
DefaultMutableTreeNode vegetableNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Vegetables");
vegetableNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Capsicum"));
vegetableNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Carrot"));
vegetableNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Tomato"));
vegetableNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Potato"));
root.add(vegetableNode);
```

But my tree, once the root node is specified, is incrementally built. So I'd like my `JTree` to add a node under a specific parent at any time.

Please note that the tree will also be built inside a recursive method. Which means the main `JTree` object should be created outside this method.

The tree may have more than one layer, which means the path from the node to a leaf may require e.g. 10 jumps.

What is the best way of adding a node to a `JTree` at run-time which only knows about its parent?

A caveat here is when two different parents have the same name e.g. if node *apple* should go under a node called *fruit* but *fruit* is found in two different paths

```
root -> aaa -> bbb -> ccc -> fruit
root -> aaa -> fff -> ggg -> hhh -> fruit
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look into providing your own **tree model** then.

Quoting the Oracle [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#data) for JTree:

> One of the ways you can lazily load children of a Tree is by utilizing the TreeWillExpandListener interface. For example, you can declare and load root, grandparent and parent of a Tree along with the application as shown in the following code:

Given the comments by the OP: the `DefaultMutableTreeNode` does not support "names". That would mean: you need to implement that yourself, in a super simply approach, probably like:

```
class MyTreeNode extends DefaultMutableTreeNode {
   private final String name;

   MyTreeNode(String name, ... whatever ) {
     ...
     SOME_NODE_REGISTRY.put(name, this);
   }
```

Then you need to provide that registry, probably as some sort of singleton map instance. In other words: you have to write code that A) enables you to store nodes by name to then B) identify/find nodes by name.

Comment: Is there a way to capture a specific `DefaultMutableTreeNode` object by its name?  If I manage to have unique node names, then this might do the job.

Comment: @Disasterkid: that's really your responsibility, to provide a [mcve] code post in your question, one that GhostCat and we could work with

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels how can I provide a minimal for the solution I am asking for. I am not facing any errors.

Comment: @Disasterkid: that's up to you, but you're asking for considerable work from anyone answering the question, and the least you could do is to make it as easy to do this as possible by providing at the least a framework with which others can work from. Understand that questions are answered by volunteers, and in this situation the greater part of effort should come from the one asking the question.

Comment: @GhostCat thank you so much for the effort. I am going through all `DefaultMutableTreeNode` methods and as you say, capturing a specific node by name does not seem to be one of them. My method probably should be placed inside a class that implements  `JTree` where we get a list of all the nodes in a tree and then add a node to a specific node.

Comment: @GhostCat you guidance is much appreciated. But the answer you provided is not yet concrete. I will wait a short while at that. Meanwhile, if you edit the answer I will gladly accept it as the answer. This tree structure with Java has taken way longer than I expected and `JTree` is apparently far from a comprehensive library.

Comment: He's actually criticizing your answer for not being concrete enough without posting any concrete MCVE code himself? And I thought I've seen everything

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am not criticizing anyone's answers. My question was whether we can dynamically create `JTree` nodes so that we could use them in a recursive way. If I accept GhostCat's answer, then the next person wondering about the same thing will end up with a suggestion that is accepted as the solution. I still appreciate workarounds for what `JTree` apparently lacks. I am not sure if MCVE applies here but I will try to provide a simplified version of my question maybe.

Comment: Appreciated. But then we should also stop having this meta discussion. I went forward and deleted my comments, maybe you folks do the same. Still, @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for nicely writing up what I had in my mind, too.